# Default start page for web application in eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a web application, and I want to set a `servlet` as the default index page :

This is the link for my `servlet` :

```
http://localhost:8080/qcm/Accueil
```

I want when I write this link : `http://localhost:8080/qcm`, to open the `Accueil servlet`.

How can I do this ?

when I googled about it I found that I have to change the `welcome-file-list` in `web.xml`, bu there is no `web.xml` file in my project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is right. `web.xml` should be located in your `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` directory (if you use standard Maven layour) - if not, just place it under the `WEB-INF` folder in your project. You can copy it from this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/) and just add

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>qcm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

on the end, that should do it.